# Getting average number of uploads (or something else) per day

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if I'm using the wrong SE network for this question.

I'm in need of fetching the average number of uploads and registrations to my website per day. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out the math for this task. In my database tables for uploads and registrations, I have columns which indicate when the row was created, which stores an UNIX timestamp.

How would I calculate the average number of rows created per day?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: I guess I just need the algorithm/formula for this one. But okay, I'll update my post now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select avg(anz) from (
    select
    date(from_unixtime(your_TS_column)) as my_date,
    count(*) as anz
    from
    your_table
    group by my_date
) subquery_alias
```

Comment: What is `anz` referring to?

Comment: anz is the alias for the count(*) column. Name it whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the no of rows and filter by uploaded days 
I think your query should like this,

```
Select count(*) no_of_uploads FROM UPLOAD_TABLE_NAME WHERE 1 AND OTHER_CONDITIONS GROUP BY DAY(UPLOAD_DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to see how many record in your table and divide the number by the cont of the days  the code will be

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `your_table`;");
$n=mysql_num_rows($q);


$d=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `your_table` GROUP BY DATE(`date_column`);");
$m=mysql_num_rows($d);
echo ($n/$m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some very random answers here with no explanation. So to answer your question it seems like you need the maths for average uploads and average registrations?

You will need first day, total registrations and total uploads.
$total_uploads and $total_registrations needs to be fetched from database

```
$first_day = strtotime("01-01-2013"); //if you want to average from the first of january 2013
$time = time(); //current time

$total_days = ($time - $first_day) / 60 / 60 / 24; //gives you total days
$average_registrations = $total_registrations / $total_days;
$average_uploads = $total_uploads / $total_days;
```